# C++ Console Output to cmd Goes Wrong After Ten Repeats

Tags: c++, cmd

The point of my code is to print to console, showing either **RED, BLUE, GREEN, or OFF** when provided with **r, b, g, or o** keyboard input. **x** keyboard input terminates.

A bunch of **SPACE** characters are also output, with background colour set in order to display a solid block of colour in the terminal:

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<21;i++) {    // for loop to print a load of empty lines
    cout << "                                             \n";
}   // end of for loop
```

It all works to start with, however after the tenth change (i.e. pressing **r, b, g, or o** followed by **ENTER**), the solid block of colour spills past the **\n** character.

Can anyone tell why this happens?

I also expected that the else statement in **int main()** would handle any inputs that didn't match the expected **r, b, g, o or x**.
It works for single characters, but if more than one character is entered it goes all screwy, scrolling continuously and not stopping for input.

Why is this?

Full code (Compiled with MinGW g++.exe via NppExec, run in cmd on Win7):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

/*******FUNCTION PROTOTYPES*********/
void TermClr(int ClrHeight);
void SetColor(int value);
void PrintOut(int output, int col1, int col2);

/*******MAIN PROGRAM****************/
int main() {

    int output = 0; // variable for current colour being output, 0-3 for OFF, RED, BLUE, GREEN
    char inkey[2];  // console input written to the INKEY variable
    PrintOut(0,119,7);  // calls printout function, dark grey background for the light, normal grey for text

    while(1){   //while loops forever until break
        cin.getline(inkey,2);   //waits for input, stored to INKEY
        if(!strcmp(inkey,"x")){     // string compare whether INKEY matches "x"
            cout << "\nProgram Terminated in\n3...";
            Sleep(1000);
            cout << "\n2...";
            Sleep(1000);
            cout << "\n1...";
            Sleep(1000);
            break;  //breaks if 'x' is input
        }   // end if inkey x
        else if(!strcmp(inkey,"o")){
            PrintOut(0,119,7);  // calls PrintOut function, 'output' set to 0, red background for the light, red for text
            continue;
        }   // end of if inkey o
        else if(!strcmp(inkey,"r")){
            PrintOut(1,204,12);
            continue; 
        }   // end of if inkey r
        else if(!strcmp(inkey,"b")){
            PrintOut(2,153,9);
            continue; 
        }   // end of if inkey b
        else if(!strcmp(inkey,"g")){
            PrintOut(3,170,10);
            continue; 
        }   // end of if inkey g
        else{
            TermClr(30);
            printf("Input not recognized\n(x=terminate, o=off, r=red, b=blue, g=green)");
            continue;
        }   // end of else 
    }   //end of while
return 0;
}   // end of main

/*******FUNCTIONS*******************/
// function to clear terminal - ClrHeight is the number of new rows, use enough in the function call to clear the terminal
void TermClr(int ClrHeight) {
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < ClrHeight; i++ ) {
    putchar('\n');
    }   // end of for loop
}   // end TermClr

// function for changing terminal font colours (run the exe in cmd prompt to see colours, doesn't work in nppexec)
void SetColor(int value){
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),  value);
}   // end SetColor

// function to print the required text to terminal
void PrintOut(int output, int col1, int col2) {     // three inputs needed, the 'output' variable 0-3, the light colour text type, and the writing text type
    TermClr(5);         // calls func to clear teminal, 5 rows
    const char *light[4] = {"OFF", "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN"};     // defines the four light colours
    SetColor(col1);
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<21;i++) {    // for loop to print a load of empty lines with the background colour 'col1'
        cout << "                                             \n";
    }   // end of for loop
    SetColor(7);
    cout << "\nColour - ";
    SetColor(col2);         // calls the function to change the console font colour (shows if run in cmd prompt, but not nppexec console)
    cout << light[output];
    SetColor(7);
    cout << " (Output " << output << ")\n(x=terminate, o=off, r=red, b=blue, g=green)";
}   //end PrintOut
```

---

**EDITED TO ADD:**
[image showing the issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RENwj.png)
I have tried using std::endl in place of \n, it makes no difference

**FURTHER EDIT:**
If I reduce the number of iterations in the for loop for the solid colour, i.e.

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<3;i++) {    // for loop to print a load of empty lines
    cout << "                                             \n";
}   // end of for loop
```

and so printing less lines in total for each time through the while loop, I get a lot more changes before the output spills over, but it still happens after enough times.

**EDIT 3:**
Mark Ransom in the comments has identified the cmd window as the culprit for the first issue. Increasing the buffer height allows for more program cycles before bad behaviour. (ALT+SPACE, Properties, Layout Tab)
James Whyte's answer fixes the problem with multiple keyboard inputs, although I do need to do a little work so that bad input is ignored instead of each character being interpreted separately

**EDIT 4:**
If I use `system("CLS")` instead of adding new rows to clear the screen the buffer size no longer matters (guess it's cleared each time this is called). I know this is bad practice, but hell, it works! Anyone got an alternative that isn't bad practice?

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue. Please supply screenshots to show the issue. Furthermore, have you tried to use std::endl instead of "\n" ?

Comment: Interesting. I can replicate the problem, but don't understand it either.

Comment: std::endl instead of \n gives same result, image added showing screen grabs.

Comment: I suspect is has something to do with terminal window scrolling behavior. What size terminal window are you using?

Comment: @Mark You've nailed it - in cmd, ALT+SPACE > Properties, Layout tab. Increase screen buffer height (I tried 1000 vs. default 300). Now the program can do more cycles before the problem appears. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit]
!- At least this is the fix for the looping forever on two character problem.

The issue arising is due to using a char array as opposed to a singular char, I believe. I took in your code into a new project and replicated your issue without issue (funny joke), and decided to do a little fixer-upper to remove the bug.

The problem occurred when you attempted to get the line into the char array that already had a value inside it that was not cleared. It just decided to step over it, ending in a never-ending loop case.

```
/*******MAIN PROGRAM****************/
int main() {

int output = 0; // variable for current colour being output, 0-3 for OFF, RED, BLUE, GREEN
char inkey;  // console input written to the INKEY variable
PrintOut(0, 119, 7);  // calls printout function, dark grey background for the light, normal grey for text

while (1) {   //while loops forever until break
    cin >> inkey;   //waits for input, stored to INKEY
    if (inkey == 'x') {     // string compare whether INKEY matches "x"
        cout << "\nProgram Terminated in\n3...";
        Sleep(1000);
        cout << "\n2...";
        Sleep(1000);
        cout << "\n1...";
        Sleep(1000);
        break;  //breaks if 'x' is input
    }   // end if inkey x
    else if (inkey == 'o') {
        PrintOut(0, 119, 7);  // calls PrintOut function, 'output' set to 0, red background for the light, red for text
        continue;
    }   // end of if inkey o
    else if (inkey == 'r') {
        PrintOut(1, 204, 12);
        continue;
    }   // end of if inkey r
    else if (inkey == 'b') {
        PrintOut(2, 153, 9);
        continue;
    }   // end of if inkey b
    else if (inkey == 'g') {
        PrintOut(3, 170, 10);
        continue;
    }   // end of if inkey g
    else {
        TermClr(30);
        printf("Input not recognized\n(x=terminate, o=off, r=red, b=blue, g=green)");
        continue;
    }   // end of else 
}   //end of while
return 0;
}   // end of main
```

In finality, if you need only to read in a single char at any point, don't use a char array and string compare. Compare individual chars like above, or better yet, use a switch case something along the lines of the following just so it's more readable.

```
switch (inkey)
{
case 'r': PrintOut(1, 204, 12); continue; // Print red square.
case 'g': PrintOut(2, 153, 9); continue; // Print green square.
case 'b': PrintOut(3, 170, 10); continue; // Print blue square.
case 'o': PrintOut(0, 119, 7); continue; //Print a grey block for inactive.
case 'x':
    cout << "\nProgram Terminated in\n3...";
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "\n2...";
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "\n1...";
    Sleep(1000);
    break;  //breaks if 'x' is input
default: 
    TermClr(30);
    printf("Input not recognized\n(x=terminate, o=off, r=red, b=blue, g=green)");
    continue;
} // end switch
```

Comment: This is great. I had originally tried to implement in the same way as the top fix, I think where I went wrong was using double-quotes instead of single - i.e. `if (inkey =="x")`, instead of the required `if (inkey == 'x')`. I'll hold off on marking answered while the other issue is open.

Comment: The other issue has been identified by Mark Ransom in his comment under the question - the problem was the cmd window buffer height. I've marked this answer as correct for sorting out the scrolling issue, thanks James

Answer (score 0):

Final working code posted below.

With Mark Ransom's comment under the original question, the first problem was identified as the cmd buffer height.
I solved this problem using `system("CLS");` to clear the screen. (I know this is considered bad practice, but any code I ever write will be for personal use only, and it's the only way I could get it to work).

The scrolling problem when more than one character was input was correctly identified and corrected by James Whyte in his answer, however, it revealed another problem (which in my opinion is a real shame, because I found the switch/case syntax to be so much more elegant!) -

If more than one character was entered, each individual character would be interpreted in turn and run through the while loop. Therefore, if I entered "rgb", the display would flicker through the "r" and "g" outputs before settling on the "b" output. By going back to the original character array & string compare solution, and adding an `if(inkey.length() == 1)` loop, anything other than a single character can be caught, and the user informed that the input was not valid.

Finally, I desired that on receiving invalid input, the previous displayed output would remain. This was achieved by adding variables for the previous output, and calling those for the arguments in the `PrintOut` function

Code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

    int outputprev;
    int col1prev;
    int col2prev;

/*******FUNCTION PROTOTYPES*********/
void SetColor(int value);
void PrintOut(int output, int col1, int col2);

/*******MAIN PROGRAM****************/
int main() {

    int output = 0; // variable for current colour being output, 0-3 for OFF, RED, BLUE, GREEN
    string inkey;   // console input written to the INKEY variable
    PrintOut(0, 119, 7);    // calls printout function, dark grey background for the light, normal grey for text

    while(inkey != "x"){   //while loops forever until break
        getline(cin, inkey);   //waits for input, stored to INKEY
        if(inkey.length() == 1) {
            if(inkey.compare("o") == 0){
                PrintOut(0,119,7);  // calls PrintOut function, 'output' set to 0, red background for the light, red for text
                continue;
            }   // end of if inkey o
            else if(inkey.compare("r") == 0){
                PrintOut(1,204,12);
                continue; 
            }   // end of if inkey r
            else if(inkey.compare("b") == 0){
                PrintOut(2,153,9);
                continue; 
            }   // end of if inkey b
            else if(inkey.compare("g") == 0){
                PrintOut(3,170,10);
                continue; 
            }   // end of if inkey g
            else{
                PrintOut(outputprev, col1prev, col2prev); // Print for previous value
                cout << " **INVALID INPUT**";
                continue;   }   // end of else 
        }   // end of if input length
        else {
            PrintOut(outputprev, col1prev, col2prev); // Print for previous value
            cout << " **INVALID INPUT**";
            continue;  // end of else 
        }
    }   //end of while
    cout << "\nProgram Terminating";
    Sleep(1000);
return 0;
}   // end of main

/*******FUNCTIONS*******************/
// function for changing terminal font colours (run the exe in cmd prompt to see colours, doesn't work in nppexec)
void SetColor(int value){
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),  value);
}   // end SetColor

// function to print the required text to terminal
void PrintOut(int output, int col1, int col2) {     // three inputs needed, the 'output' variable 0-3, the light colour text type, and the writing text type
    outputprev = output;
    col1prev = col1;
    col2prev = col2;
    system("CLS");
    const char *light[4] = {"OFF", "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN"};     // defines the four light colours
    SetColor(col1);
    putchar('\n');
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<20;i++) {    // for loop to print a load of empty lines with the background colour 'col1'
        cout << "                                             \n";
    }   // end of for loop
    SetColor(7);
    cout << "\nColour - ";
    SetColor(col2);         // calls the function to change the console font colour (shows if run in cmd prompt, but not nppexec console)
    cout << light[output];
    SetColor(7);
    cout << " (Output " << output << ")\n(x=terminate, o=off, r=red, b=blue, g=green)";
}   //end PrintOut
```